# Calculate IRR (Internal Rate Return) and NPV programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, excel

I am developing a financial app and require `IRR (in-built functionality of Excel)` calculation and found such great tutorials in `C` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/461049/Internal-Rate-of-Return-IRR-Calculation?msg=4616844#xx4616844xx) and such answer in `C#` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179866/xirr-calculation/6348722#6348722).

I implemented code of the C language above, but it gives a perfect result when IRR is in positive. It is not returning a negative value when it should be. Whereas in Excel `=IRR(values,guessrate)` returns negative IRR as well for some values.

I have referred to code in above C# link too, and it seems that it follows good procedures and returns errors and also hope that it returns negative IRR too, the same as Excel. But I am not familiar with C#, so I am not able to implement the same code in Objective-C or C.

I am writing C code from the above link which I have implemented for helping you guys.

```
#define LOW_RATE 0.01
#define HIGH_RATE 0.5
#define MAX_ITERATION 1000
#define PRECISION_REQ 0.00000001
double computeIRR(double cf[], int numOfFlows)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double m = 0.0;
    double old = 0.00;
    double new = 0.00;
    double oldguessRate = LOW_RATE;
    double newguessRate = LOW_RATE;
    double guessRate = LOW_RATE;
    double lowGuessRate = LOW_RATE;
    double highGuessRate = HIGH_RATE;
    double npv = 0.0;
    double denom = 0.0;
    for (i=0; i<MAX_ITERATION; i++)
    {
        npv = 0.00;
        for (j=0; j<numOfFlows; j++)
        {
            denom = pow((1 + guessRate),j);
            npv = npv + (cf[j]/denom);
        }

        /* Stop checking once the required precision is achieved */
        if ((npv > 0) && (npv < PRECISION_REQ))
            break;
        if (old == 0)
            old = npv;
        else
            old = new;
        new = npv;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            if (old < new)
            {
                if (old < 0 && new < 0)
                    highGuessRate = newguessRate;
                else
                    lowGuessRate = newguessRate;
            }
            else
            {
                if (old > 0 && new > 0)
                    lowGuessRate = newguessRate;
                else
                    highGuessRate = newguessRate;
                }
        }
        oldguessRate = guessRate;
        guessRate = (lowGuessRate + highGuessRate) / 2;
        newguessRate = guessRate;
    }
    return guessRate;
}
```

I have attached the result for some value which are different in Excel and the above C language code.

```
 Values:             Output of Excel: -33.5%
 1 = -18.5,          Output of C code: 0.010 or say (1.0%)
 2 =  -18.5,
 3 = -18.5,
 4 = -18.5,
 5 = -18.5,
 6 =  32.0

Guess rate: 0.1
```

Comment: Start with formatting your code, because this is hard to read.

Comment: You can see formatted code in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/461049/Internal-Rate-of-Return-IRR-Calculation?msg=4616844#xx4616844xx

Comment: I only see the same badly formatted code at the link; indentation with 1, 2 and 3 spaces; sooo ugly.

Comment: If you could help with the same format then it would be appreciable.

Comment: You should understand that the internal rate of return is not a well-defined function. It is generally not a function at all, since there may be multiple solutions. By opening your search results to negative rates, you may miss a positive solution that exists. People should be discouraged from using IRR as a financial criterion in the presence of cash flows with mixed signs (positive, negative, positive or negative, positive, negative). Net Present Value with a determined cost of capital is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since low_rate and high_rate are both positive, you're not able to get a negative score. You have to change:

```
#define LOW_RATE 0.01
```

to, for example,

```
#define LOW_RATE -0.5
```