# Objective C IRR calculation compared to Excel IRR function

Tags: objective-c, excel, function, irr

The discussion below provides codes in Objective C IRR calculation that is consistently incorrect when compared to Excel IRR function.  Does anyone know why there is such a difference?

The code used is offered in this previous discussion:

[Calculate IRR (Internal Rate Return) and NPV programatically in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759427/calculate-irr-internal-rate-return-and-npv-programatically-in-objective-c)

The test cash flow I am using to calculate the IRR is the following:
"Print tempCashFlow: (
    "-5099701.25",
    "-22503.796875",
    "-22503.79296875",
    "-22503.79296875",
    "-20907.26171875",
    "-17899.7421875",
    "-17899.7421875",
    "-17899.7421875",
    "-14660.69140625",
    "-12447.80078125",
    "-12447.796875",
    "-12018.1640625",
    "-5991.81640625",
    "-5991.81640625",
    "-5991.81640625",
    "-2885.875",
    "1653.125",
    "1653.125",
    "1653.125",
    "8307.328125",
    "11110408.45703125"
)

The above temporary cash flow contains quarterly figures over a 5-year period (i.e. 20 periods plus the time zero period... so 21 figures in the cash flow).

The code delivers 15.2% IRR instead of circa 16.0% produced by Excel IRR function.  I also tested it manually, and I believe 16% is the correct answer.  Can anyone help understand what may be wrong with the code?  I cannot see any issues.  It also appears to be identical to code promoted on this link as well:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/461049/Internal-Rate-of-Return-IRR-Calculation

PS: I've also noticed that the margin of error increases dramatically if I reduce the cash flow to a 2-year period instead of a 5-year period (e.g. something like 35% (incorrect) versus 45% IRR (correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

The IRR for that series of cash flows as reported by Excel's `IRR` function is `3.803961%` (but that assumes they were annual cash flows). That C algorithm you reference returns `3.803961%`, as well. So, there is no discrepancy between these two calculated values. And if I apply that rate as I sum the NPV of all of those annual cashflows, I get zero, verifying that `3.803961%` is correct IRR.

You haven't shared how you're using either Excel `IRR` or this function's to handle quarterly cash flows, but I suspect that you may be simply multiplying this C function's resulting value by four, which is not correct. You have to apply quarterly compounding to it. If I do the former, I reproduce your incorrect value of `15.215842%`, but if I do the latter, I get the correct value, `16.106276%`. And, again, verifying this by calculating the cumulative NPV of these cash flows, I get zero, confirming that `16.1%` is the correct IRR for this series of quarterly cash flows.

Comment: Rob - you are absolutely correct. Thanks - my error.  I was using XIRR instead of IRR function to check, and the code was assuming annual cash flows instead of quarterly.