# TIR.NO.PER excel function on C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to use the TIR.NO.PER excel function in C#, is there a way to accomplish that?

Basically I have a list of dates and a list of numeric values and can create a dictonary or whatever is needed.

Comment: [That appears to be a Spanish name](http://en.excel-translator.de/xirr/) for the Excel function `XIRR`. In which case, that's [been answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179866/xirr-calculation).

Comment: Thanks, os what I have being looking for :)