# Formula Evaluator for XIRR function in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xirr

Facing issue with reading a cell in excel which is set with XIRR function. 
I written my code in Java. Below is the code to set the formula. Please help on how can I read the value from the cell and not the formula.

```
cell.setCellFormula("XIRR(E2:E10, B2:B10");        
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00%"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Below is the error while evaluating the cell using **FormulaEvaluator**

```
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: XIRR
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.atp.AnalysisToolPak$NotImplemented.evaluate(AnalysisToolPak.java:59)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.UserDefinedFunction.evaluate(UserDefinedFunction.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:129)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Contribute an implementation of this missing function to the Apache POI project?

Comment: @Gagravarr - I've gone through the java code that calculates XIRR. The issue is that the return value is not matching with the value that calculated through XL (the difference is not more than 0.2). If we can modify the java code or contribution of this implementation to Apache POI both the cases will do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without patching apache poi with `XIRR` function directly calculating a result like Excel's [XIRR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/XIRR-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d) is possible using a [User Defined Function](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) in apache poi.

The following code provides exactly this.

It defines a class `CalculateXIRR` which then will be used as `myXIRR` function in apache poi. The `CalculateXIRR` uses either [JXIRR - v1.0.0](https://github.com/ept/jxirr) (C) 2005 Gautam Satpathy or class `Xirr` derived from [java program to calculate XIRR without using excel or any other library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789967/java-program-to-calculate-xirr-without-using-excel-or-any-other-library) to calculate XIRR.

Also it provides code for test cases. At first the same test case as from the example in Excel's XIRR documentation. And then random test cases using random values and dates. Those test cases are written into an Excel workbook. Written are the result of the evaluation of the user defined `myXIRR` function as well as Excel's original `XIRR` function. So we can comparing the results.

My tests have shown that both XIRR calculation methods are pretty exact like Excel using reasonable values and dates. Only using values and dates which leads Excel's XIRR resulting in high negative percentages (lower than -60%) or very high percentages (greater than 1000%) both methods are different from Excel.

`JXIRR - v1.0.0` from Gautam Satpathy is better suited to Excel as the class `Xirr`. The reason is pretty clear since the class `Xirr` will always fail if  `x` in `Math.pow((x + 1d), (dt0-dt) / 365d)` is lower than `-1d`. If so, then the base of the `Math.pow` function is negative and since the exponent `(dt0-dt) / 365d)` is fractional, there is only a imaginary solution. This happens if Excel's XIRR is resulting in high negative percentages and the approximation tries to come from below -100%. `JXIRR` uses a goal seek method which seems to be more like the one of Excel itself.

Code:

```
import java.io.* ;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.* ;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.* ;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.* ;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.* ;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.* ;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.* ;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Random;

/*
https://github.com/ept/jxirr
(C) 2005 Gautam Satpathy
*/
import in.satpathy.financial.*;

public class XIRREvaluator {

 private Workbook workbook;
 private Sheet sheet;
 private Row row;
 private Cell cell;
 private CellStyle percentStyle;
 private CellStyle dateStyle;
 private FormulaEvaluator evaluator;
 private String[] labels;
 private char c1;
 private char c2;
 private String[] formulas;
 private Double[] values;
 private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
 private Date[] dates;


 public XIRREvaluator() {
  this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  String[] functionNames = { "myXIRR" } ;
  FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls = { new CalculateXIRR() } ;

  UDFFinder udfs = new DefaultUDFFinder( functionNames, functionImpls ) ;
  UDFFinder udfToolpack = new AggregatingUDFFinder( udfs ) ;    

  workbook.addToolPack(udfToolpack);

  this.percentStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  percentStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00%"));
  this.dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  dateStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));

  this.evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  this.sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  this.labels = new String[]{"XIRR", "myXIRR", "diff"};

  this.sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 }

 public void save() {
  try {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelWorkbookXIRR.xlsx"));
   workbook.close(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }       
 }

 private void testCaseFromExcelDocu(int startCol, int startRow) {

  /*
   This provides a test case as from the example in Excel's XIRR documentation:
   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/XIRR-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d
  */

  if (startCol > 24) return;

  try {
   c1 = (char)(65+startCol);
   c2 = (char)(65+startCol+1);
   formulas = new String[]{"XIRR("+c1+(startRow+4)+":"+c1+(startRow+8)+","+c2+(startRow+4)+":"+c2+(startRow+8)+")", 
                           "myXIRR("+c1+(startRow+4)+":"+c1+(startRow+8)+","+c2+(startRow+4)+":"+c2+(startRow+8)+")", 
                            ""+c2+(startRow+1)+"-"+c2+(startRow+2)};

   values = new Double[]{-10000d, 2750d, 4250d, 3250d, 2750d};

   dates = new Date[]{sdf.parse("2008-01-01"), sdf.parse("2008-03-01"), sdf.parse("2008-10-30"), sdf.parse("2009-02-15"), sdf.parse("2009-04-01")};

   for (int r = startRow; r < startRow+3; r++) {
    row = (sheet.getRow(r)==null)?sheet.createRow(r):sheet.getRow(r);
    cell = row.createCell(startCol);
    cell.setCellValue(labels[r-startRow]);
   }

   for (int r = startRow+3; r < startRow+8; r++) {
    row = (sheet.getRow(r)==null)?sheet.createRow(r):sheet.getRow(r);
    cell = row.createCell(startCol);
    cell.setCellValue(values[r-startRow-3]);
    cell = row.createCell(startCol+1);
    cell.setCellValue(dates[r-startRow-3]);
    cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
   }

   for (int r = startRow; r < startRow+2; r++) {
    cell = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(startCol+1);  
    cell.setCellFormula(formulas[r-startRow]);
    cell.setCellStyle(percentStyle);
    if (r == startRow+1) {
     cell = evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
     System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell)); 
    }
   }

   cell = sheet.getRow(startRow+2).createCell(startCol+1);          
   cell.setCellFormula(formulas[2]);        

   sheet.autoSizeColumn(startCol);
   sheet.autoSizeColumn(startCol+1);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }       
 }

 private void randomTestCases(int startCol, int startRow, int count) {

  /*
   This provides randon test cases
  */

  try {
   long day = 24L*60L*60L*1000L;
   long startDate = sdf.parse("2010-01-01").getTime();

   for (int test = startCol; test < startCol+3*count; test+=3) {

    if (test > 24) return;

    c1 = (char)(65+test);
    c2 = (char)(65+test+1);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rows = 5+rnd.nextInt(5);

    formulas = new String[]{"XIRR("+c1+(startRow+4)+":"+c1+(startRow+3+rows)+","+c2+(startRow+4)+":"+c2+(startRow+3+rows)+")", 
                           "myXIRR("+c1+(startRow+4)+":"+c1+(startRow+3+rows)+", "+c2+(startRow+4)+":"+c2+(startRow+3+rows)+")", 
                           ""+c2+(startRow+1)+"-"+c2+(startRow+2)};

    values = new Double[rows];
    values[0] = -1d*(rows-1d)*(1000+rnd.nextInt(5000));
    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
     values[i] = 1d*(1000+rnd.nextInt(5000));
    }

    dates = new Date[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
     dates[i] = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date(startDate+=day*(1L+rnd.nextInt(150)))));
    }

    for (int r = startRow; r < startRow+3; r++) {
     row = (sheet.getRow(r)==null)?sheet.createRow(r):sheet.getRow(r);
     cell = row.createCell(test);
     cell.setCellValue(labels[r-startRow]);
    }

    for (int r = startRow+3; r < startRow+3+rows; r++) {
     row = (sheet.getRow(r)==null)?sheet.createRow(r):sheet.getRow(r);
     cell = row.createCell(test);
     cell.setCellValue(values[r-startRow-3]);
     cell = row.createCell(test+1);
     cell.setCellValue(dates[r-startRow-3]);
     cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
    }

    for (int r = startRow; r < startRow+2; r++) {
     cell = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(test+1);  
     cell.setCellFormula(formulas[r-startRow]);
     cell.setCellStyle(percentStyle);
     if (r == startRow+1) {
      evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
      cell = evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
      System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell)); 
     }
    }

    cell = sheet.getRow(startRow+2).createCell(test+1);          
    cell.setCellFormula(formulas[2]);        

    sheet.autoSizeColumn(test);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(test+1);

   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }     
 }

 public static void main( String[] args ) {

  XIRREvaluator xirrEvaluator = new XIRREvaluator();
  //test case as from the example in Excel's XIRR documentation
  //starting on column 0, row 0
  xirrEvaluator.testCaseFromExcelDocu(0,0);

  //9 random test cases
  //starting on column 0, row 10
  xirrEvaluator.randomTestCases(0,10,9);

  //9 random test cases
  //starting on column 0, row 25
  xirrEvaluator.randomTestCases(0,25,9);

  xirrEvaluator.save();

 }
}

/* 
 Class for user defined function myXIRR
*/
class CalculateXIRR implements FreeRefFunction {

 @Override
 public ValueEval evaluate( ValueEval[] args, OperationEvaluationContext ec ) {

  if (args.length < 2 || args.length > 3) {  
   return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
  }

  double result;

  try {

   double[] values = ValueCollector.collectValues(args[0]);
   double[] dates = ValueCollector.collectValues(args[1]);

   double guess;
   if(args.length == 3) {
    ValueEval v = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[2], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex()) ;
    guess = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(v);
   } else {
    guess = 0.1d;
   }

   result = calculateXIRR( values, dates, guess ) ;

   checkValue(result);

  } catch (EvaluationException e) {
   //e.printStackTrace();
   return e.getErrorEval();
  }

  return new NumberEval( result ) ;
 }

 public double calculateXIRR(double[] values, double[] dates, double guess ) {
  double result;

  /*
   Either calculating XIRR using https://github.com/ept/jxirr (C) 2005 Gautam Satpathy
  */

  XIRRData data = new XIRRData(values.length, guess, values, dates);
  result =  XIRR.xirr(data) - 1d;


  /*
   Or calculating XIRR Class Xirr 
   from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789967/java-program-to-calculate-xirr-without-using-excel-or-any-other-library
  */

  //result = Xirr.Newtons_method(guess, values, dates);

  return result;
 }

 static final void checkValue(double result) throws EvaluationException {
  if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result)) {
   throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
  }
 }

 static final class ValueCollector extends MultiOperandNumericFunction {
  private static final ValueCollector instance = new ValueCollector();
  public ValueCollector() {
   super(false, false);
  }
  public static double[] collectValues(ValueEval...operands) throws EvaluationException {
   return instance.getNumberArray(operands);
  }
  protected double evaluate(double[] values) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("should not be called");
  }
 }

}

/*
 Class Xirr from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789967/java-program-to-calculate-xirr-without-using-excel-or-any-other-library
*/
final class Xirr {

 private static final double tol = 0.00000001;    

 private static double f_xirr(double p, double dt, double dt0, double x) {
  double resf = p * Math.pow((x + 1d), (dt0-dt) / 365d);
  return resf;
 }

 private static double df_xirr(double p, double dt, double dt0, double x) {        
  double resf = (1d / 365d) * (dt0-dt) * p * Math.pow((x + 1d), ((dt0-dt) / 365d) - 1d);
  return resf;
 }

 private static double total_f_xirr(double[] payments, double[] days, double x) {
  double resf = 0d;
  for (int i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
   resf = resf + f_xirr(payments[i], days[i], days[0], x);
  }

  return resf;
 }

 private static double total_df_xirr(double[] payments, double[] days, double x) {
  double resf = 0d;
  for (int i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
   resf = resf + df_xirr(payments[i], days[i], days[0], x);
  }

  return resf;
 }

 public static double Newtons_method(double guess, double[] payments, double[] days) {
  double x0 = guess;
  double x1 = 0d;
  double err = 1e+100;

  while (err > tol) {
   x1 = x0 - total_f_xirr(payments, days, x0) / total_df_xirr(payments, days, x0);
   err = Math.abs(x1 - x0);
   x0 = x1;
  }

  return x0;
 }
}
```

Comment: definitely this solution helps. Well deserved 50.