# How to calculate the XIRR formula in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, calculation

How to implement the XIRR formula in C# like MS Excel?. It would be great if you could supply some example coding.

Reference link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xirr-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XIRR Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179866/xirr-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

Excel Formula Syntax

XIRR (values, dates, [guess])

The XIRR function syntax has the following arguments:

Values (required): A series of cash flows that corresponds to a schedule of payments in dates. The first payment is optional and corresponds to a cost or payment that occurs at the beginning of the investment. If the first value is a cost or payment, it must be a negative value. All succeeding payments are discounted based on a 365-day year. The series of values must contain at least one positive and one negative value.

Dates (required): A schedule of payment dates that corresponds to the cash flow payments. Dates may occur in any order. Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as results of other formulas or functions. For example, use DATE (2008,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2008. Problems can occur if dates are entered as text.

Guess (optional): A number that you guess is close to the result of XIRR.

Example:
=XIRR(B2:B4,A2:A4)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq65o.png)

Possible Error:

1. Forgetting to add a negative sign.
2. False Date
3. Former Dates
4. Unrecognizable entry